# Using R to scrape a web page?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to download data from [here](https://experience.arcgis.com/experience/478220a4c454480e823b17327b2bf1d4/page/page_1/) the left nav-bar.
I have tried the following :

```
library("rvest")
page <- html("https://experience.arcgis.com/experience/478220a4c454480e823b17327b2bf1d4/page/page_1/")
page %>%
   html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="ember39"]/div[2]/nav') %>% html_text()

character(0)
```

And also the :

```
page %>%
   html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="ember39"]/div[2]/nav') %>% html_table()

list()
```

I would appreciate any help or suggestion.

Comment: This is a very javascript-heavy dashboard, and the numbers you see in the left navbar are dynamically loaded from xhr requests - they are not present in the html source you are downloading. There are far easier ways to get the data you need. You could try scraping the data from [the table on the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_Germany#Timeline_of_cases) or [directly from the Robert Koch Institute](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Fallzahlen.html). The best way to scrape this page if you really want to is with RSelenium.

Comment: @AllanCameron, Thanks for your reply, I have already checked those sources, they don't provide the statistics per city, but just per state. This dashboard has the statistics per city. I would appreciate if you could help me by RSelenium.

Comment: RSelenium is a complex topic, and I'm not able to give a tutorial here. You can be sure someone else has already collected the data you are looking for into an easily obtainable format. Have you looked at https://github.com/jgehrcke/covid-19-germany-gae ?

Comment: @AllanCameron This is the only source I have found so far which has the weekly data :https://www.citypopulation.de/en/germany/covid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is easily available from one of the endpoints you can find in the network tab. It returns json. You can parse out what you want.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(magrittr)

data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://services7.arcgis.com/mOBPykOjAyBO2ZKk/arcgis/rest/services/RKI_Landkreisdaten/FeatureServer/0/query?f=json&where=1%3D1&returnGeometry=false&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=*&orderByFields=cases%20desc&resultOffset=0&resultRecordCount=1000&resultType=standard&cacheHint=true') %>%
        .$features

#e.g.
print(data[[1]]$attributes)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! would you please explain where did you get that url ?

Comment: I opened network tab in dev tools with F12 then F5 to refresh page and filtered on xhr.  I then used search box to look for a city name and saw the json url. Extracted into a json viewer to double check.